# Why is there an underscore in front of the MongoDb document id?

Tags: mongodb

Why is there an underscore in front of the MongoDb document id ?

Why not call it "id" instead of "_id" ?

Is this part of a naming convention I'm not aware of ?

Comment: Not as far as I know but sometimes you put a `_` in front of variables to denote a `private` or `read only` attribute of a class, even though `_id` is settable in insert it is read only every other time, just a wild guess there but a adds up

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may notice that MongoDB has a lot of functions (in the shell) and fields that start with an understore as a designation that they are internal or special and not user provided.

If you have your own "ID" then you can store it as "id" and still use the provided-by-MongoDB _id field although you are not required to use the ObjectId that MongoDB generates - you could store your own natural primary key in the "_id" field which will have a unique index on it always.