# How do I add a close button to a FullCalendar event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am learning how to append a close button to dynamically created selectable events in FullCalendar. I found a demo that uses the eventRender callback to append a close button to selectable events as they are created. However, I don't understand why an underscore "_" was added to "event._id" inside this callback. Is it necessary to have this underscore? Could someone perhaps explain this concept? Here is the demo to which I am referring. Thanks!

HTML

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },
    defaultView: "month",
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: false,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

    select: function(start, end) {
      var title = prompt("Event Content:");
      var eventData;
      if (title) {
        eventData = {
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end
        };
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventData, true); // stick? = true
      }
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    },

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element
        .find(".fc-content")
        .prepend("<span class='closeon material-icons'>&#xe5cd;</span>");
      element.find(".closeon").on("click", function() {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", event._id);
      });
    },

    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
      var title = prompt("Edit Event Content:", calEvent.title);
      calEvent.title = title;
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);
    }
  });
});
```

CSS

```
    body {
  margin: 40px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrap {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.closeon {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

/*info btn*/
.dropbtn {
    /*background-color: #4CAF50;*/
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

.dropdown-content p {
    color: black;
    padding: 4px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: grey;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn span {color: white}
```

Comment: My understanding is that `._id` represents the internal unique ID generated by fullCalendar when an event is added to the calendar. So therefore that's what you would use to identify it when you want to delete it.

Comment: Just a guess, but I'd assume that this convention was carried over from [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) at some point. That's the only other place I've seen this used [Why is there an underscore in front of the MongoDb document id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480934/why-is-there-an-underscore-in-front-of-the-mongodb-document-id). Mongo is pretty ubiquitous in the JS community.   In Mongo this is used to access their version [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) called [ObjectIds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

Comment: So do you both think that the eventRender callback will work without the underscore in "event._id"?

Comment: No, I didn't say that at all. I just told you what the _id field represents. It would likely only work without the underscore if you'd explicitly set an `id` field yourself in the event data you passed to fullCalendar. But I could be wrong...why not try it and see?